# A "security" key in the payload for login into a website (using Python requests library)

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to login to a website using Python's `requests` library

When using the `request.post` method, the data I need to put in are shown below
[image]

The data are obtained by inspecting the Network tab as I click the login button. As I use the same payload info to login through `request.post`, I can successfully use Python to access the site and scrape the stuff I want. However, it turns out that a while later (I am not exactly sure how long), my script will no longer work, and it turns out that the "security" key is wrong. I then need to inspect the Network manually and obtain the new "security" key and update to my login data for my scraper to work properly again.

I can use `Selenium` to do the login process (and have succeeded). With `Selenium` Python can directly interact with elements of the website like a real human and my scraper is totally free from this problem, but can I bypass this "security" key with only `requests`?

Comment: "I then need to inspect the Network manually and obtain the new security key" Can you automate that part? I am just guessing here but that security key might be a token that has a life time. Once expired, you need to obtain a new one.

Comment: I am not sure how to automate this. What I do is to manually open the site, right click and inspect elements. The "Network" tab will show what I post to the site when I click the submit button, and the security key is in the payload.

Answer (score 0):

The situation you're encountering is likely due to the use of anti-CSRF tokens (such as the "security" key you mentioned) as a security measure on the website.

These tokens are designed to prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks, where unauthorized actions are performed on behalf of a user. The anti-CSRF token changes each time a user logs in or performs specific actions, which is why you're experiencing difficulties when using a static token.

To bypass the anti-CSRF protection using the `requests` library, you would need to retrieve the correct anti-CSRF token dynamically from the website and include it in your POST request.

You can achieve this by making an initial **GET** request to the login page, extracting the token from the response, and then using it in your subsequent **POST** request.

Example:

**1 - Perform Initial GET Request:**

Send an initial **GET** request to the login page using `requests.get()`. Parse the HTML response to extract the anti-CSRF token.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

loginUrl = 'https://YourWebAPP.com/login'
response = requests.get(loginUrl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

csrf_token = soup.find('input', {'name': 'security'})['value'] # Use apropriate selector for the element
```

**2 - Login with Extracted Token:**

```
data = {
    'username': 'your_username',
    'password': 'your_password',
    'security': csrf_token,  # Use the extracted token
    'lang': 0
}

loginResponse = requests.post(loginUrl, data=data)
```

**Conclusion:**

Remember that the exact method to extract the token and the form structure might vary depending on the website's structure. You might need to adjust the code to fit the specific website you're working with.

Using a tool like Selenium, as you've mentioned, is often more reliable when dealing with websites that employ complex security mechanisms, as it allows you to interact with the page as a real user would. However, if you prefer to stick with requests, dynamically extracting and using the anti-CSRF token is the recommended approach.